# haussdorfness $\iff$ limits of all nets are unique

Tags: general-topology, nets

> Prove that topological space $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if limits of all nets
>   in it are unique.

Let $X$ be Hausdorff and $S:D\to X$ be a net in it where $D$ is a directed set. Let $S$ has two limits $x,y\in X$. We need to prove that $x=y$. Suppose $x\neq y$, therefore by Hausdorffness, there exists $U,V$ open sets in $X$ containing $x,y$ respectively such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$. Now by defintion of convergence, there exist $m_1,m_2\in D$ such that for all $n\in D$, $n\geq m_1$ implies $S(n)\in U$ and $n\geq m_2$ implies $S(n)\in V$. Again by definition of directed set, there exists $n\in D$ such that $n\geq m_1$ and $n\geq m_2$. This implies $S(n)\in U\cap V$, a contradiction. Hence $x=y$ and our first part is proved.

Now for the converse, if we take limits of all nets are equal, and WLOG assume $X$ is not Hausdorff. Then for $x,y\in X$, $x\neq y$, we would have two open sets containing $x,y$ respectively which are not disjoint. But I can't get a contradiction this way. How to proceed for this converse part? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You just have to construct a net which converges to two at least two limits. Hint: even a sequence works.

Comment: I don't see what's stopping you from reversing everything in the first part.  Besides, you're attempt at the converse is misdirected.  If $X$ is not Hausdorff, then _any_ open sets containing $x$ and $y$ respectively intersect nontrivially, for some $x\ne y$.  But, from this it becomes possible to get a net that converges to both $x$ and $y$.  So your logic broke down a bit.

Comment: @Keen-amateur I don't think you can necessarily find a _sequence_ converging to both $x$ and $y$.  But you can find a _net_.  Nets are more general.  If the space were first countable, then you could get a sequence.  Check me on this.

Comment: Wouldn't the sequence $z_{2n}=x$ and $z_{2n+1}=y$ work?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Not necessarily. You're banking on every open set that contains $x$ to also contain $y$, and vice-versa. This is a lot stronger than a failure in Hausdorffness.

Comment: @user757704 I'm actually banking on just direction of what you stated. In essence if we assume WLOG that $x$ is contained in every open set containing $y$, then every sequence\net which has $y$ as limit also has $x$ as a limit. Or at least I think so.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Smallest possible example: $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$, and $\tau = \{\emptyset, X, \{1, 2\}, \{2, 3\}, \{2\}\}$. Note that $(X, \tau)$ is a topological space, that $1$ and $3$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets, but the sequence $1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, \ldots$ does not converge to $1$ or $3$. Specifically, if we take the open neighbourhood $\{1, 2\}$ of $1$, then the sequence is not eventually inside this neighbourhood. (On the other hand, the constant sequence $2$ converges to both $1$ and $3$, as well as $2$.)

Comment: Okay, thanks for that clarification. Perhaps what I had in mind was the negation of $X$ being $T_1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is not Hausdorff. Then there exist some distinct $x, y \in X$ such that, for all open neighbourhoods $U$ and $V$ of $x$ and $y$ respectively, $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$.

Define the directed set
$$A = \{(U, V) : \text{$U, V$ are open and } x \in U, y\in V\},$$
with the partial order
$$(U_1, V_1) \le (U_2, V_2) \iff U_1 \supseteq U_2 \text{ and } V_1 \supseteq V_2.$$
Given $(U_1, V_1), (U_2, V_2) \in A$, we can define an upper bound
$$(U, V) = \left(U_1 \cap U_2, V_1 \cap V_2\right).$$
Choose (with axiom of choice) a net $(x_{(U, V)})_{(U, V) \in A}$ such that
$$x_{(U, V)} \in U \cap V.$$
I claim that $x_{(U, V)} \to x, y$.

For any open neighbourhood $U_0$ of $x$, we have
$$(U, V) \ge (U_0, X) \implies x_{(U, V)} \in U \cap V \subseteq U \subseteq U_0,$$
hence $x_{(U, V)} \to x$. A similar argument works for $y$ too.

Comment: I presume you can define the upper bound $(U,V)$ as above since $U_1\cap U_2\subseteq U_2$ and $V_1\cap V_2\subseteq V_2$?

Comment: @am_11235... Yes, the neighbourhoods of a point are directed under reverse inclusion; this is a very commonly used idea in nets.